# Python printing objects - TypeError: must be str, not Address

Tags: python, console

I have `Person` and `Address` classes. Each `Person` holds an `Address`.

Code:

```
class Address: 
    def __init__(self, street, town, city, postcode, country):
        self.street = street
        self.town = town
        self.city = city
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.country = country

    def __str__(self):
        return ("\t"   + "Street: " + self.street +
                "\n\t" + "Town: " + self.town + 
                "\n\t" + "City: " + self.city + 
                "\n\t" + "Postcode: " + self.postcode +
                "\n\t" + "Country:" + self.country)

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, phone, address):
        # instance variables, unique to each Person
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: " + self.name + "\n" + "Age: " + self.age + "\n" + "Phone: " + self.phone + "\n" + "Address: " + self.address
```

However, when I call `print(p)` where `p` is a `Person`, I get the following exception:

```
  File "phone2.7.py", line 30, in __str__
    return "Name: " + self.name + "\n" + "Age: " + self.age + "\n" + "Phone: " + self.phone + "\n" + "Address: " + self.address
  TypeError: must be str, not Address
```

Can anyone pinpoint what the issue is here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add `string` and `object`. It's not enough that you override the `__str__` method in your `Address` class. You need to call `str()` method.

```
"Address: " + str(self.address)
```

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on why str() needs to be called explicitly? (The object is referenced in a string context, so why doesn't it use `__str__`?)

Comment: it is better to convert all the fields to string before concatenating so that there are no errors when some one passes interger values to Age/Phone number

Comment: @AndyG __str__ is called only when you are printing the object or when you call str() on that object, basically it is a special method which is used to convert an object to string, and won't be called automatically when you are trying to concatenate

Comment: Thanks, coming from the Java world, my default expectation was that `__str__` would've been implicitly invoked.  In situations like this, it's important to remember that Python is a [strongly typed language](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/static-vs-dynamic-typing-of-programming-languages/).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Address: 
def __init__(self, street, town, city, postcode, country):
    self.street = street
    self.town = town
    self.city = city
    self.postcode = postcode
    self.country = country

def __str__(self):
    return ("\t"   + "Street: " + self.street +
            "\n\t" + "Town: " + self.town + 
            "\n\t" + "City: " + self.city + 
            "\n\t" + "Postcode: " + self.postcode +
            "\n\t" + "Country:" + self.country)
class Person:
def __init__(self, name, age, phone, address):
    # instance variables, unique to each Person
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.phone = phone
    self.address = address

def __str__(self):
    return "Name: " + str(self.name) + "\n" + "Age: " + str(self.age) + "\n" + "Phone: " + str(self.phone) + "\n" + "Address: " + str(self.address)
```

p = Person(1,2,3,4)
print p

Comment: You should explain your answer rather than just posting code.

Comment: i will take care of it from next time.. thanks for advice @andy G

Answer (score 1):

Before concatenating using `+`, the `self.address` object must be converted to string using `str()` function.

```
class Person:

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: " + self.name + "\n" + "Age: " + self.age + "\n" + "Phone: " + self.phone + "\n" + "Address: " + str(self.address)
```